# In DialogFlow, I am getting all the responses mentioned in an intent instead of one. How can I fix this?

Tags: dialogflow-es

For an intent that I have, I ask the user to enter the error message they see on the screen. Based on the message they enter, I want to show them a response. I have added these responses in the intent (all separate responses). I have annotated the training phrases (exact copy of the error messages) to an entity that captures these messages. When I enter the error message however, I get all the responses instead of just the relevant one.

How should I solve this? I would like to control which response gets selected based on the error message the users enter. I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I was able to get this right. If I have different responses in an intent, all of them will be displayed. I have added the different responses I had as variants within the same response and I was able to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this right. If I have different responses in an intent, all of them will be displayed. I have added the different responses I had as variants within the same response and I was able to get it working!